# Date will not echo out correctly when using the date function

Tags: php

Maybe I am having a brain fart but this:

```
$dob = date ("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['dob']));
```

$dob is displayed as 1970-01-01

even though the value of $_POST['dob'] is 10/5/66.

Am I missing something here?

UPDATE: I found that if the POST is 10/5/1966 then it works.  So I guess if the date of birth is earlier than 1/1/1970, you need the 4 digits!
However, if the dob is more recent than 1/1/1970, then 2 digits will be assumed to be 19xx

Comment: `strtotime` wants a 4 digit year.  66 could really be 1866 couldn't it? Or 2066.

Comment: Is that October 5th? Or May 10th?

Comment: Also as @JohnConde states, `strtotime` sees `m/d` when you use `/` and `d-m` when using `-`.

Comment: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here and see how this site works! http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

This is likely the PHP's strtotime() function, that it only supports restricted date ranges as documented in the [Notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) section

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
> 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates
> that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed
> integer.)
>
> Prior to PHP 5.1.0, not all platforms support negative timestamps,
> therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix
> epoch. This means that e.g. dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work
> on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few other operating
> systems.

strtotime("10/5/66") in your snippet translates to the year 2066 and you are on a stack where it doesn't work implying the date shown as unix epoch.

Using this way wouldn't be a problem if you are using a 64-bit PHP.  Alternately, you can use the DateTime class.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) and it should work for you:

```
$_POST['dob'] = "10/5/66";

$date = new DateTime($_POST['dob']);
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Output:

```
2066-10-05
```

Or better with the format:

```
$_POST['dob'] = "10/5/1966";

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $_POST['dob']);
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: So that will be their birthday in 51 years when they are born?